# Asp.net app deployed on IIS server hosted on DMZ NIC, unable to get response from service fabric application

Tags: azure, iis, dmz

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.238.79.45:443

The error occurs when Application hosted on a on-premises IIS server tries to hit an API in Azure Service fabric cluster. We even allowed Any-Any connections on firewall to confirm if firewall is blocking but we got the same error. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

impossible to know with the information provided, but applications on service fabric can be called from outside, so you need to check your setup

Comment: Sounds like a comment, other than answer.